# Picklist Text to Numerical Value

Tags: custom-object, formula-field, picklist

I am putting together an evaluation form in Salesforce. I am using Customer object Greeting__c, the pick list values are High, Met, Below. I would like to assign a formula that sets "High" to numerical value 4 , "MET" to 2 and "Below" to 0. I cannot figure out how to configure the formaula. 
1st question: Do I create a formula field to reference the Greeting_c API or create the formula in the Greeting__c in the formul editor?

Based on other questions here, I am trying (Greeting__c,"High",4) to return the picklist selection "High" with the number value 4. I am a beginner at this. Thank you in advance for your help. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CASE() function. Create a new formula field that returns a Number, and uses the following formula:

```
CASE(Greeting__c),
  "High", 4,
  "Met", 2,
  0
)
```

What this will do is return 4 for High, 2 for Met, and 0 by default (e.g. Below).

For more information, see the [CASE() formula field reference in Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5#CASE).